# How to speed up matchTemplate when there are only 2-tone grayscale?

Tags: opencv

I want to speed up the `matchTemplate` operation.

Resizing using `resize` is the best way, but in my situation, the recognition rate decreased dramatically when the pixels were squashed.
However, it was not sensitive to color.
There was no difference between color and 256-tone grayscale, and it was almost three times faster.

This time, I made it 2-tones using `threshold`, and the recognition rate was still high. However, there was no change in speed.
I understand. The amount of data for 256-tone grayscale and 2-tone grayscale was the same, only the data was simplified.

I already divide the image by the number of CPU cores and process it in parallel. CPU occupancy is 100%.

Any other ideas to speed up `matchTemplate` in this situation?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] showing matching and timing, also add your representative image. Thank you.

Comment: Template matching will match the whole template in many scales over the full image, this needs the same processing time no matter how the pixel values are. Can you show a sample image? If the object can only be at white thresholded positions you could first extract contours and then perform matchTemplate only at contour positions.

Comment: opencv's template matching works on _one_ scale only. it tests all locations.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Nonetheless the amount of computation doesnt change with the pixel intensity ;)